# Only first table is found useing simple html dom

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

SO I'm using *simple html dom*, to read all the id's from my table.

My tables looks like this:

```html
<table><a name="Module-277409-Start_5f7bad2c-10af-4c88-afaf-6c960be2f547"></a><a name="Module-277409-Start"></a><span class="text_class2"><span>ID</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class9 cell_class8"><span class="text_class2"><span>Primary Text</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class11 cell_class10"><span class="text_class2"><span>SystemFeatures</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class13 cell_class12"><span class="text_class2"><span>Area of Relevance</span></span></td></tr><tr class="row_class14"><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class7 cell_class15"><a class="hyperlink_class16" href="">1</a></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class9 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><h1 class="paragraph_class17 1"><span>XXXXX</span></h1></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class11 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>XXXX</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class13 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>HEADING</span></span></td></tr><tr class="row_class14"><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class7 cell_class15"><a class="hyperlink_class18" href="">2</a></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class9 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><h2 class="paragraph_class19 2"><span>XXXXXX</span></h2></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class11 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>XXXX</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class13 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>XXXX</span></span></td></tr><tr class="row_class14"><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class7 cell_class15"><a class="hyperlink_class20" href="">3</a></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class9 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><p class="paragraph_class21"><span class="paragraph_class21 text_class22">xxxxx</span></p></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class11 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>XXXXXX</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class13 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>SW</span></span></td></tr><tr class="row_class14"><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class7 cell_class15"><a class="hyperlink_class23" href="">4</a></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class9 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><p class="paragraph_class21"><span class="paragraph_class21 text_class22">XXXXX</span></p></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class11 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>xxxxx</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class13 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>SW</span></span></td></tr>
</table>
<table><a name="Module-277409-Start_5f7bad2c-10af-4c88-afaf-6c960be2f547"></a><a name="Module-277409-Start"></a><span class="text_class2"><span>ID</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class9 cell_class8"><span class="text_class2"><span>Primary Text</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class11 cell_class10"><span class="text_class2"><span>SystemFeatures</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class13 cell_class12"><span class="text_class2"><span>Area of Relevance</span></span></td></tr><tr class="row_class14"><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class7 cell_class15"><a class="hyperlink_class16" href="">1</a></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class9 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><h1 class="paragraph_class17 1"><span>XXXXX</span></h1></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class11 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>XXXX</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class13 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>HEADING</span></span></td></tr><tr class="row_class14"><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class7 cell_class15"><a class="hyperlink_class18" href="">2</a></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class9 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><h2 class="paragraph_class19 2"><span>XXXXXX</span></h2></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class11 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>XXXX</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class13 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>XXXX</span></span></td></tr><tr class="row_class14"><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class7 cell_class15"><a class="hyperlink_class20" href="">3</a></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class9 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><p class="paragraph_class21"><span class="paragraph_class21 text_class22">xxxxx</span></p></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class11 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>XXXXXX</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class13 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>SW</span></span></td></tr><tr class="row_class14"><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class7 cell_class15"><a class="hyperlink_class23" href="">4</a></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class9 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><p class="paragraph_class21"><span class="paragraph_class21 text_class22">XXXXX</span></p></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class11 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>xxxxx</span></span></td><td class="table_class4DeffCell cell_class13 cell_class15"><span class="text_class2"><span>SW</span></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is my code where i find the ID's:

```php
$html = file_get_html('../Test/reqID/htmlfileID.html');

$table = $html->find('table');

foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    if (is_numeric($row->find('td',0)->plaintext)) {
        $reqIDs[] = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext; 
    }         
}
```

Here there is a screen snip of the .html open in chrome:
[image: html from chrome]

Why can it be that I only get the Id's from the first table and not the others? I've got like 25 tables with Id's in it. All Id's is the first column in each table, or as I do, find every table, and search for  first numeric value in the td.

**EDIT:**

Thanks guys,

For some reason It stop almost at the end of table 4 now? i still got like 10 tables left? There is alot of Id's.

This is how my tables look, and I got many divs with new tables in them.
[image: table]

Also when I do sizeof($table), it says 9 tables found. but i do have 30?
[image]

Comment: why you add 0 in ` $html->find('table',0); ` . i think due to this it selects first table only

Comment: Please avoid putting your code (the HTML part) as image. It will prevent readers from running your code with same input as you, so they can't help.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter passed to `find()` method in  line `$table = $html->find('table',0);` tells this method to return only the first found element (the second argument is the index of the element in result array), so you are basically asking `find` method to only return the first table. To avoid that, you need to omit the second parameter. Something like this:

```php
$html = file_get_html('../Test/reqID/htmlfileID.html');

// $tables will be an array of all found tables
$tables = $html->find('table');

// you will need to also loop over all tables
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
        if (is_numeric($row->find('td',0)->plaintext)) {
            $reqIDs[] = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext; 
        }         
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nima but how come it stop mid table 4? still got some tables with id's, wrote some in Edit field in the question.

Comment: @NalinNishant Not unexpected. The required change is so small that it was probable for two people to come up with same solution :)

Comment: I changed it to `$tables = $html->find('table')`, but it still stop at table 4.

Comment: @Mads he already tell you a logic do some experiement.. well I think the problem is because you are again using the 0 in `$row->find('td',0)` that means you are selecting an only first row. remove 0 and use foreach for each row.

Comment: But I only need that from the td, everything else in the td is not somthing i need. I just dont understand why it "crases" when mid reading id's in table 4, and then dosn't read the id's after that one.